# DefaultProps structure for a React component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am actually learning how to design React components, and I need to create a DefaultProp for a property on it. This is my code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class Component extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href={this.props.element.value1}>{this.props.element.value2}</a>
      </li>
    )
  }
}    

Component.defaultProps = {  // does not set the default value when value1 is not passed
  element: {value1: '#', value2: 'foo'}
}

export default Component
```

As my property `element` has two properties (`value1` and `value2`) I find myself unable to refer to it before accesing its properties and set the default value.

I've also tried these variations, resulting all of them on an error:

```js
Component.defaultProps = {
  element.value1: '#'
}

Component.defaultProps = {
  this.props.element.value1: '#'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `propType` of `element` is `shape` with `value1` and `value2` properties you need to set an object as default value with those properties:

```
Component.defaultProps = {
  element: {value1: '#', value2: 'foo'}
}
```

Note that the default value is only used if you don't give any `element` prop to the component, i.e.

```
<Component element={{value1: '#'}}/>
```

will not add the `value2` prop for you. If that's what you want, you need to do it yourself:

```
render(){
    const value2 = this.props.element.value2 || 'default-value'
    return(
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href={this.props.element.value1}>{value2}</a>
      </li>
    )
  }
```

And then you shouldn't specify `value2` as `isRequired`.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I have tried this with no success. It does not throw an error but neither does apply any default value when property is not passed. I have edited the question, removing the propType in order to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ES6 `default arguaments`. It is worth reading about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Description) it states:

> In JavaScript, function parameters default to undefined. However, it's often useful to set a different default value. This is where default parameters can help.

An example to help explain is the following

```
function getInfo (name, year = 2018, color = 'blue') {
  console.log(name, year, color);
}

getInfo('Chevy', 1957, 'Green');  // result --> "Chevy" 1957 "Green"
getInfo('Benz', 1975);  // result  --> "Benz" 1975 "blue"
getInfo('Honda');  // result  --> "Honda" 2018 "blue"
```

I would recommend something like the following.

```
  render() {
    const {
      value1 = 'defaultValue1',
      value2 = 'defaultValue2'
    } = this.props;

    return(
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href={value1}>{value2}</a>
      </li>
    )
  }
```

If `value1` or `value2` props are undefined then it will default to the value you enter.